# Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError - External libraries

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, libraries, nosuchmethoderror

Hi i am  trying to use some external libraries, the things is thats their are aparently detected in compile time

[image]

Because i can go to the reference
[image]

But when i try to run it i get the following error

[image]

What is strange to me is that the file that contains the method does not appear in my external files
When i search for it in the files it supposed to appear here
as rememberLottieComposition.kt
but instead  only appear RememberLottieCompositionKT.class

[image]

BTW, when i look in my files the file that contains the missing method exist

[image]

So no idea how to solve it, i have tried a lot but no results.

**Any idea of what may it be will really help!**

Thank you in advance

This is my build gradle:App

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
```

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.perri"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
    //de 1.5.1
}
```

}

//compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'
dependencies {

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"



//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' // appcompat library
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'


implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'



implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.0.0"

implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:4.0.0"
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.0-beta01"



implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'


//swipe
implementation 'it.xabaras.android:recyclerview-swipedecorator:1.2.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.compose:compose-runtime:0.1.0-dev10'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
```

}

And this is the other build Gradle
[image]

Comment: Did you imported it with `import com.airbnb.lottie.compose.rememberLottieComposition`?

BTW, next time please insert code samples and error messages as a text and not as screenshots.

Comment: Yes, I import it, but still get the same message     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method rememberLottieComposition$default. I've read that it may be an error version of compile time and the version of the runtime, but i don't know how to check the version, neither how to update it propertly, any idea how to solve this, or where I can get info about this? Thank you!